# Dnsmasq unable to resolve local host

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, mac-osx, dnsmasq

I'm unable to get my local DNS server to work and totally stumped. Here's what I have done so far to make it work...

**Dnsmasq configured on Ubuntu 18.04 ( Static IP: 192.168.1.100)**

*/etc/resolv.conf*

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

*/etc/dnsmasq.conf*

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv

domain=example.dev
expand-hosts
local=/example.dev/

interface=enp4s0
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.100   test
192.168.1.101   storage
```

**Restarted networking services and dnsmasq**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart  
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

*Netstat confirms that Dnsmasq is listening on 53 as it should*

```
netstat -an | grep 53.  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**Configured my MacBook Pro to use the newly configured DNS server.**

*scutil --dns*

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.100
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.8.8
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)
```

**Test host resolution using NSLookup**

*nslookup*

```
> server 192.168.1.100
Default server: 192.168.1.100
Address: 192.168.1.100#53
> test.example.dev
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Your `netstat` output indicates that **dnsmasq** is only listening on TCP/53 while it should also listen on UDP/53.

Comment: Thanks Tom. It is actually listening on UDP 53 as wll. I just didn't include that from the netstat output. my bad.